C# secret access on local and Kubernites
I am looking for a way to access my secrets from Kubernetes and locally in my C# project.
Locally I have my secrets.json:
{
  "OpenAi": {
    "Key": "<Key>"
  },
}

And I have my Kubernetes secrets.yaml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: app-secrets
  namespace: <namespace>
type: Opaque
data:
  OPENAI_KEY: <Key Base64 encoded>

that I like it in my Kubernetes config:
valueFrom:
  secretKeyRef:
    name: app-secrets
    key: MAIL_HOST

I tried to get the secrets with this:
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OPENAI_KEY")

and this
builder.Configuration["OPENAI_KEY"];

didn't work on remote and local. The second only worked on local. So how can I access secrets on Kubernetes and locally without changing code?

Can you post your [mre] of how you config your configurations? Make you you did call ConfigurationBuilder.AddEnvironmentVariables() Microsoft Documentation
Then for your local secret json file, you can add code to load it during startup. However it is better you add secret by .NET CLI dotnet secrets set command

IIUC you want to ensure consistent access to (secret) data from your process when deployed either locally (non-Kubernetes|non-Container) or (containerized) on Kubernetes? There are many ways to do this including using environment variables and using volumes|files. Since you have  secrets.json file, it would be simplest to create a generic secret, then mount the secret as a file in your Pod(s)

Kubernetes - not "Kubernites" ....
